# Is there a way to capture the output of a command, and its return value into variables in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

So, let's say that I have a command, `foo`, in a script which has both a return value, and an output string that I'm interested in, and I want to store those into a variable (well at least its output for the variable, and its return value could be used for a conditional).

For example:

```
a=$(`foo`)   # this stores the output of "foo"
if foo; then # this uses the return value
    stuff...
fi
```

The best thing that I could think of to capture that output is to use some temporary file:

```
if foo > $tmpfile; then
    a=$(`cat $tmpfile`)
    stuff...
fi
```

Is there anyway I could simplify that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this?

```
out=$(cmd)
rv=$?
if test $rv -eq 0; then
  echo "all good"
  echo $out
else
  echo "wtf, exit code was $rv"
fi
```

btw, $() and backticks are two syntaxes for the same effect, which means that you *only* want to write

```
$(`foo`)
```

if `foo` outputs a text of a command you want to execute again. like:

```
foo()
{
  echo echo date
}
$(foo)
$(`foo`)
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the backticks thing.  I'm not sure why I put those there.

Answer (score 3):

```
output=`foo`
echo "Return: $?" # $? is the return code
```

Answer (score 2):

From bash: (note the first $ in the first column is my prompt)

```
$ A=$(echo abc; false); echo status:$? A:$A
status:1 A:abc
```

Don't use `$()` plus backticks, as that actually executes the command and then executes its output.

See also:

- [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)
- [Unix shell quote tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide
- http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/